# What function has the signature $ A \times \left ( B + C \right ) \rightarrow \left ( A \times B \right ) + \left ( A \times C \right ) $?

Tags: functional-programming, ct.category-theory

$ A \times \left ( B + C \right ) $ is isomorphic to $ \left ( A \times B \right ) + \left ( A \times C \right ) $, right? That means there's a function from one to the other and another function back. But what are those functions? Furthest I got was $ \left < \mathrm { p } _ 0 , ( \mathrm { id } + \mathrm { id } ) \circ \mathrm { p } _ 1 \right > $ but that's just equal to $ \mathrm { id } _ { A \times \left ( B + C \right ) } $.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: You can ask elementary questions in computer science on http://math.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 11):

Here is a proof that this is not a research question. It can be solved by a *machine*:

```
Welcome to Djinn version 2011-07-23.
Type :h to get help.
Djinn> f ? (a, Either b c) -> Either (a,b) (a,c)
f :: (a, Either b c) -> Either (a, b) (a, c)
f (a, b) =
    case b of
    Left c -> Left (a, c)
    Right d -> Right (a, d)
```

Comment: To be fair, the version number indicates solving it by machine would count as a valid research question :-).

Comment: I am pretty sure even very early versions of Djinn could solve this one.